# Does every open set of a differentiable manifold have a local coordinate system?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

A differentiable manifold is first a topological space.

By definition,a $C^r$ manifold $M$ has an open set cover $\{(U_{\alpha},\phi_{\alpha})\}_{\alpha\in\Gamma}$ , $\phi_{\alpha}$ is a homeomorphism and $\phi_{\alpha}\circ \phi^{-1}_{\beta}$ is $C^r$.

But the open cover is not required to be a topology on $M$,that is,not every open set is defined to have a local coordinate system.

**Question:**

Does every open set of a differentiable manifold have a local coordinate system?

**Attempt**:

$\forall open\ U \subset M,U=\cup_{\alpha\in\Gamma}(U\cap U_{\alpha})$ .We can assume that $U_{\alpha}\cap(\cup_{\beta\neq\alpha}U_{\beta})^c\neq\emptyset$ .

I try to define $\phi$ as $\phi_{\alpha}$ on $U_{\alpha}$ .It's okay when $p\in U_{\alpha}\cap(\cup_{\beta\neq\alpha}U_{\beta})^c$ , but it's tough to deal with the overlapping parts(especially with the boundary).

---

Now we have a counterexample - $S^n$ itself is open but it's not covered by one chart.

And a result:coordinate neighborhoods form a basis for a topology of any manifold.

Comment: Hint: The whole topological space is always open.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!But I think maybe not every manifold has one coordinate system on the whole topological space?(like S^n?)Or do you mean something that is not about taking the restriction of $\phi$?

Comment: The comment above is a counterexample - the whole manifold itself is not covered by one chart (in general) and it's a valid open subspace.

Comment: There is a slightly weaker result though: coordinate neighborhoods form a basis for the topology of any manifold.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments!